# Method not found: 'Int64 RelationalExtensionInfo.GetServiceProviderHashCode()'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have upgraded my application SDK and dependencies from dotNet core 2.1 to dotNet core 6 But I am facing issue while running database stored procedures. The code which I am using to run stored procedures is

```
 public int ExecuteProcedure(string procedure, params object[] parameters)
    {
        List<OracleParameter> oracleParameterList = ((List<OracleParameter>)parameters[0]);
        string[] oracleParameters = new string[oracleParameterList.Count];
        string query = "BEGIN " + procedure + "(";
        for (int i = 0; i < oracleParameterList.Count; i++)
        {
            OracleParameter parameter = oracleParameterList[i] as OracleParameter;
            oracleParameters[i] = ":" + parameter.ParameterName;
        }
        query += string.Join(",", oracleParameters);
        query += "); end;";
        return Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(query, oracleParameterList);
    }
```

The line which is producing error is return **Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(query, oracleParameterList);** .For database connectivity I am using Devart ORM.

**Error**

```
System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Method not found: 'Int64 RelationalExtensionInfo.GetServiceProviderHashCode()'.
  Source=Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.EFCore
  StackTrace:
   at Devart.Common.Entity.EntityOptionsExtension.get_Info()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions.GetHashCode()
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TArg](TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.GetOrAdd(IDbContextOptions options, Boolean providerRequired)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.get_Dependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IDatabaseFacadeDependenciesAccessor.get_Dependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetFacadeDependencies(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRaw(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, String sql, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at IFFCO.HRMS.Entities.Models.ModelContext.ExecuteProcedure(String procedure, Object[] parameters) in C:\Users\110393\Desktop\update SDK 6\trunk\IFFCO.HRMS.Entities\Models\ModelContext.cs:line 648
   at IFFCO.HRMS.Service.AccountService.ValidateUser(LoginModel loginModel) in C:\Users\110393\Desktop\update SDK 6\trunk\IFFCO.HRMS.Service\AccountService.cs:line 60
   at IFFCO.HRMS.Web.Controllers.AccountController.Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel) in C:\Users\110393\Desktop\update SDK 6\trunk\IFFCO.HRMS.Web\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 73
```

Comment: Have you updated all EF packages to their latest versions as well (especially `Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore`)?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Yes I have updated all the dependencies  and nuget packages

Comment: The [nuget page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore/) says it only supports 5.0 or below. Maybe you have to wait for Devart to upgrade their package for 6.0?

Comment: It might also help to downgrade all the Microsoft EF packages to a version before 6.0 again. That would be 5.0.12. I'm not sure how well they work with dotnet 6.0 though.

Comment: If you check the "Dependencies" tab of the [nuget page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore/) you'll see that it says `>= 5.0.12 && < 6.0.0` for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`. So you definitely can't use the latest Microsoft EF packages with the Devart EF package.